# Optimal algorithm for seeing who won a tick tac toe game

Tags: java, algorithm, tic-tac-toe

I have a completed tic tac toe game board. It is 3 x 3. Im not really asking for code (although that would help), but what algorithms would be best for seeing who won? Another way to phrase it would be, what algorithms should I research that would be useful to see who won?

The only thing that really comes to mind is brute force. Just test all the possibilities, but I know there has to be a better way.

Comment: Loop through the rows, then loop through the columns, then check the diagonals.

Comment: are you asking about AI? like alpha beta prunning on min-max trees? or pattern search in tic-tac-toe game matrix?

Comment: More like a static search. The game is already completed. It is in a text file. I read in the text file, and need to determine who won. But it has to be as optimal as possible. So I dont need to determine what the best next move would be or anything like that.

Comment: Remember that the standard algorithm performs 24 operations. Solving the problem dynamically can incur memory-allocation delays that prevent the theoretical time complexity from being experimentally more efficient on small data sets (for example, merge sort). Are we really arguing about optimization techniques for tic-tac-toe?

Comment: What makes you say that there's a better way?

Comment: Yes, I think there's a more optimal way than repeated brute force, to determine if a tic-tac-toe game has a winner or is draw.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 13):

An important lesson I recently (re-)learned: when the search space is small enough, just use brute force.

On a 3x3 board there are eight possible winning sequences (the rows, columns, and diagonals.) That gives you 24 comparisons to verify if one has the same player marking in all it cells. 24 comparisons take no time at all even on a very slow computer.

Comment: ...and: "small" is often unexpectedly large.

Answer (score 3):

Here is **the best**, **clever** and **optimal** algorithm: (This is a well known trick, so I don't boast, only praise the algorithm)

**Definitions**: The cells are named as follows:

```
A31  A32  A33
A21  A22  A23
A11  A12  A13
```

The pieces are W(hite) or B(lack). There are 8 winning combinations: [A11,A12,A13], [A11,A21,A31], [A13,A22,A31] etc. Give each combination a name: C1..C8.:

```
C1 =def= [A11,A12,A13]
C2 =def= [A21,A22,A23]
C3 =def= [A31,A32,A33]
C4 =def= [A11,A21,A31]
C5 =def= [A12,A22,A32]
C6 =def= [A13,A23,A33]
C7 =def= [A11,A22,A33]
C8 =def= [A13,A22,A31]
```

Define a mapping from cells to a set of winning combinations:

```
A11 --> C1,C4,C7
A12 --> C1, C5
A22 --> C2, C5, C7, C8
```

etc.

So every cell A points to those combinations that has A in it.

Keep a set of possible winning combinations for both players. In the beginning both players have all 8 combinations.

```
Poss_W = C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8
Poss_B = C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7, C8
```

When W plays in a cell A, delete the corresponding winning combinations from B. For example when white plays A12, delete C1, C5 from Black's possible winning combinations list.

After the game ends, the player with a nonempty possible winning combinations set wins. If both Poss_W and Poss_B is empty, the game is a draw.

Comment: The algorithm does not depend on the order of moves; you can wait for the game end if you want. You can first "play" all black moves and then all white moves if you want. You can take the finished board and read the cell values (B or W) in any order and apply the moves if you want. The algorithm applies to a game in progress **and** to a finished game.

Comment: hum, this is not much different from my approach.

Comment: Perhaps the algorithm does not shine very much because TicTacToe is a simple game. However, it is a very powerful idea (to explicitly enumerate "solutions" and map elements to solution sets) that can be used in more complex games and puzzles as well. Let's play a game where we place tetris pieces on a chess board and the first one unable to move loses. The algorithm can be modified to quickly see if a list of moves lead to a terminal board position or not. (Elements: single piece placement; Combinations: the set of all elements; i.e. each placement makes some other placements impossible)

Answer (score 2):

Just use a map `diagonal -> number of checks in that diagonal`.

When one of the entries is equal to three, you have a winner.

Answer (score 0):

A slight optimization for tic-tac-toe comes from knowing there can't be a winner until the 5th move.  Therefore, if your game keeps a move count, you can reduce the number of times you check the entire board state.

Another optimization is knowing that, if your algorithm finds any row, column, or diagonal containing both an X and an O, then it can never be a winner.  You don't need to check it again. You can eject those un-winnables from your search space.

A side effect of the above optimization, is that it may let you detect a draw sooner than waiting for the board to fill up, in cases where the search space becomes empty.

Answer (score 0):

Simple problems are best to solve with simple code.

Here is a brute force and straight forward javascript ES6 solution

```js
const tictactoeBoard = ['x', 'o', 'x',
                        'o', 'x', 'o',
                         '', 'o', 'x'];

const winningCombinations = [
    /// horizontal
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 5, 6],
    [6, 7, 8],
    /// vertical
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    /// diagonal
    [0, 4, 8],
    [6, 4, 2],
];

const checkForWinner = () => {
    for (const c of winningCombinations) {
        const fieldsToCheck = [
            tictactoeBoard[c[0]],
            tictactoeBoard[c[1]],
            tictactoeBoard[c[2]]
        ];
        /// check if every fields holds a trueish value and
        /// is the same value across the array aka won the game
        if (
            fieldsToCheck.every(f => f && f === fieldsToCheck[0])
        ) {
            return fieldsToCheck[0]
        }
    }
    return
}

console.log(checkForWinner());
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have to check after each step whether the game ended, you can cache the temporary results.

For each row, column, and diagonal store the number of marks for each player. Increment the appropriate values after each step. If the number is 3, you have a winner.

Answer (score -2):

There's no way to determine a winner without checking the entire board state. If you want to perform the check at the end of each turn, iterate through each row, column, and both diagonals, checking for equality (ex: `board[0][0] == board[1][0] == board[2][0]` and so on). If you want to want to keep track of the board state while the tic-tac-toe game is being played, you can use [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), though it's major overkill. A dynamic approach would be useful if you're using abnormally large boards which would otherwise require a huge number of steps to find a winner. It's also worth noting that standard tic-tac-toe's are small enough that an efficient algorithm doesn't impact performance in the slightest.

Comment: Constructive criticism please?